# Measure distance between two lines

Tags: image, opencv

I'm doing traffic tracking and i want to calculate the width of a lane. I'v used Canny edge detector to detect the lines forming the lane but don't know how to measure the distance between the lines. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Hough transform http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform to get the parameters of your line. With the parameters, it shouldn't be a problem to calculate the distances.